# in wordpress get post methods does not work

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have made a site in Wordpress.

In my `front-page.php` and in my `index.php` files I entered both post and get methods just to echo a message in `page-message.php` file.

When I click the subscribe button the posts `page:news` appears.The posts `page:news` is defined in my Wordpress settings: dashboard=>settings=>reading=>Front page displays=>a static page.

In `page-message.php` I wanted to show the data I had entered from this form. T

**Code for the forms:**

```
<h2>Sign to Newsletter</h2>
<form action="page-message.php" method="post">
    Name:<input class="input" type="text" name="name" value=""/><br/>
    Email:<input type="text" name="email" value=""/>
    <br/><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Subscribe"/>
</form>
```

**Code for page-message.php:**

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    echo 'Congratulations!You have been successfully subscribed to our newsletter' .$name .$email;                
?>
```

When I click the subscribe button my url changes to `http://localhost/wordpress/page-message.php?name=stergios&email=something%40someone.com`.

This seems to be correct when using the post method. The problem is the content!

It always loads the news (posts page from settings =>reading) and not the simple echo message?

It always shows the posts page when I write anything beyond my pages in the url. For example the url `localhost/wordpress/hhhhhhhhhhh` (a page that does not exist) does load the posts page and not a message error!

Answer (score 0):

I know the reason why it is not working.

```
action="page-message.php"
```

your static page's path should be `/wp-content/themes/{themename}/page-message.php` u can try it,

```
 action="<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>/page-message.php"
```

But I don't think it will work. You can try

```
 action="/index.php"
```

It is untested. let me know if it work.

Update: As you set that page as front page, then your wordpress root url will be that page's url (example.com or example.com/wpdirectory). Then simply do it,

```
action="/"
```

or

```
action="/wpdirectory"
```

Comment: no it did not work!i tried <form action="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/page-message.php" method="post"> in both files index.php and in front-page.php the content was correct but the url was http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/revenant/page-message.php?name=stergios&email=something%40someone.com which is incorrect.It should be localhost/wordpress/page-message

Comment: just try `index.php` or `/` I checked `$_get[]` method and it worked this way

Answer (score 0):

if "page-message.php" is a custom template in your theme you can get the page ID where it is assigned to with following query:

```
$get_message_pageId = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'  => 'page',
    'meta_key'   => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'page-message.php'
));
```

and then you can set the action with:

```
action="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $get_message_pageId->posts[0]->ID ) ); ?>"
```

so you will always have the correct URL in your form, but it will only work if you have 1 page where this template is assigned to

Comment: i do not want to set my page-message.php to custom template.but if i do you mean i have to make another custom template with this only one page?besause i have one custom template.I created a page message and in dashboard when i click in view page the url is correct like this http://localhost/wordpress/page-message/ without the php extension.But if i go in the front-page and put the data in my form as i mentioned in the above comment the url is http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/revenant/page-message.php which is incorrect.